# Creating a break line between two download links in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

Hi I am new to javascript
I wrote a javascript code for the user to download two .csv files 
1) Download Waiting Time Report &
2) Download Raw Waiting Time Report
Below is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        <?php $array =     

getCompiledRawDataForAverageWaitTimeStatisticOfMerchant($startDate, $endDate,  

$merchantID, $paxStart, $paxEnd);




        array_unshift($array,array("transactionID"=>"transactionID","merchantID"=>"merchantID","mobileNum"=>"mobileNum","capacity"=>"capacity","remarks"=>"remarks","queueStartTime"=>"queueStartTime","status"=>"status","statusTime"=>"statusTime","numPings"=>"numPings","minTime"=>"minTime","time before ping"=>"time before ping","day"=>"day"));?>
        var items = <?php 
        echo json_encode($array);?>;
        console.log(items);



        var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
        var csv = ConvertToCSV(jsonObject);

        a=document.createElement('a');
        a.textContent='Download Waiting Time Report';
        a.download="waitTime.csv";
        a.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(csv);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        ///Second thing to code:
        //document.write("\n");

        <?php $array2 =  

  getAllRawDataForAverageWaitTimeStatisticOfMerchant($startDate, $endDate, $merchantID, 

   $paxStart, $paxEnd);



 array_unshift($array2,array("transactionID"=>"transactionID","merchantID"=>"merchantID","mobileNum"=>"mobileNum","capacity"=>"capacity","remarks"=>"remarks","queueStartTime"=>"queueStartTime","final status"=>"final status","final statusTime"=>"final statusTime","status"=>"status","minTime"=>"minTime","numPings"=>"numPings","time before status change"=>"time before status change","day"=>"day"));?>
        var items2 = <?php 
        echo json_encode($array2);?>;
        console.log(items2);



        var jsonObject2 = JSON.stringify(items2);
        var csv2 = ConvertToCSV(jsonObject2);

        a=document.createElement('a');
        a.textContent='Download Raw Waiting Time Report';
        a.download="RawWaitTime.csv";
        a.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(csv2);
        document.body.appendChild(a);


    });
```

Please help 
Every Time I try to insert a break line statement, the console reads an error

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

instead of using

```
document.write("\n");
```

Comment: Hi I get a Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8

Answer (score 0):

Put your `a` elements inside of `p` elements and then append the `p` elements to the page.

```
 function appendLink() { 
        a=document.createElement('a');
        a.textContent='Download Waiting Time Report';
        a.download="waitTime.csv";
        a.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';
        var div = document.createElement('p');
        div.appendChild(a);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/kQTMY/1/

`br` tags will work, but MDN recommends using `p` elements because the line breaks don't have significant meaning like they would in an address or a poem.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br